# Creating exclusive ranges in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, range, comparable

I am just starting with [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/). I want to create a range from `1` to `n` where `n` is **excluded**. I found out that Kotlin has ranges and I can use them as follows:

```kotlin
1..n
```

But this is an **inclusive** range which includes `1` and `n`. How do I create **exclusive** ranges?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update 2022: Please use the built-in function [until](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html)**.

---

Old answer:

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but you can define an `Int` extension which creates an `IntRange` from (lower bound) to (upper bound - 1).

```
fun Int.exclusiveRangeTo(other: Int): IntRange = IntRange(this, other - 1)
```

And then use it in this way:

```
for (i in 1 exclusiveRangeTo n) { //... }
```

[Here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html) you can find more details about how ranges work.

Comment: This literally excludes the 1. This answer is deceiving

Comment: you're right, it's an old answer. You should just use the until function.

Answer (score 118):

You can use the [until](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) function in the Kotlin stdlib:

```
for (i in 1 until 5) {
    println(i)
}
```

Which will print:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Note: In Kotlin 1.1, using "until" with integers does not generate the same optimized code as writing: for (i in 1..n-1) {...}

Comment: @BladeCoder is this still true for Kotlin 1.2?

Comment: @leoderprofi Yes things have changed. "until" is now optimized since Kotlin 1.1.4

Comment: This works for the the case when the last number in the range is excluded, but what about when we want to exclude the first number?

Comment: @MikeRylander I suppose you start the loop with the indexer already having the desired value. Usually we want indexer to be one off to use a collection count to fetch indexed arrays, right?

Answer (score 8):

With Kotlin 1.8 and newer use the new **`..<`** (rangeUntil) operator:

```kotlin
for (i in 1 ..< 5) {
    println(i) // 1, 2, 3, 4
}
```

It also opens possibilities that could not be done with `until`:

```kotlin
val floatRange = 0f ..< 1f
val dateRange = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 1) ..< LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 1)
val stringRange = "1z" ..< "9a"
// OR anything implementing Comparable
```

See [official Kotlin video introducing the `rangeUntil` operator](https://youtu.be/v0AHdAIBnbs).

Answer (score 1):

The most backward compatible way is to use kotlin's `until` operator. E.g.

```
for (val i in 0 until 5){
   /*do stuff*/
}
```